# android: retain attributes children in RelativeLayout dynamically adding ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

How can I retain attributes of the children in a RelativeLayout when dynamically adding ImageViews?

I have a custom ImageView I want to add at runtime to an empty RelativeLayout (nothing inside in XML), I can add the first, then move, scale and rotate them, it works fine. 
When I add another ImageView all previously added instances loose their position and their size, but when I touch them they get back just their size, not the position.

In my ImageView I'm overriding onDraw and onTouch, do I need to override something else?
Maybe I have to write my own RelativeLayout implementation? I wouldn't!

This is the pseudocode for adding new ImageView:

```
create new instance of ImageView
set bitmap
set scaletype
add imageview to the RelativeLayout container
```

I even tried to set a standard layout parameter for the brand new added ImageView with the same result.
I tried to get the margins for every children, based on its position, and the re set the layout with ImgeView.setLayout(l, t, r, b); 
no success...

Here's the XML RelativeLayout container, pretty simple, maybe too much?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/face_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you need more details to help me? Please ask, I can post the code too, but I have to clean it up a bit before, I can do it tomorrow, in the meantime please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

In a RelativeLayout all view positions are related to the others views. So, as you do in xml, you should provide for each view the relative parameters.
Before add imageView to the RelativeLayout call `setLayoutParams(layoutParams)`:

```
// Create a new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instance
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// add roules
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layoutParams.addRule(.........
layoutParams.addRule(.........

//add params to view
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

//add imageview to the RelativeLayout container
yourRelativeLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for all rules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But what if I would like to just reassign the same position they had before (as adding one of them reset everything). Your solution doesn't seem to allow what I want to achieve. Or am I wrong? 
Here you can fine more details about my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745975/adroid-get-dimension-of-children-and-reassign-it-after-adding-another-child-view